# Does removing the US president from office through impeachment affect the validity of the decisions they made?

Tags: united-states, president, law, impeachment, executive-order

What happens to changes made by the president of the United States after her/his impeachment?
Will executive orders and such automatically be invalidated, put on hold upon revaluation, revaluated, ...?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Nothing happens.

Executive orders stay in place until they are revoked or changed by the new President (the former Vice President). The new President can do that as easily as the precedessor made them. But only if the new President wants to do that. Laws not vetoed by the last President stay valid until Congress makes new laws which revoke them, and they are under no obligation to do that. Any officials appointed by the last President stay in office until the new President replaces them (if they can be replaced - Supreme Court justices, for example, are appointed for life and thus will keep their positions).

Comment: "the new president" ...or any subsequent president.

Comment: I think if they are Executive Actions, the new President can choose to honor or dishonor them.  But what about laws signed into force (or vetoed) by the "President"?

Comment: @emory I believe I covered this in the answer: they stay in force unless congress revokes them through the regular legislative process.

Comment: Future presidents may have trouble revoking prior executive actions depending on how the Supreme Court rules on the DACA case that it's preparing to hear.  Trump was prevented from revoking DACA because his administration didn't adequately explain their decision to sundown it.  If the Supreme Court upholds that logic, future presidents will have to adequately justify their actions to the courts.

Comment: @emory If the President does not sign the bill within ten days it becomes law unless Congress has adjourned.  So, stop sending him bills to sign, wait 10 days, **then** vote.  There will be nothing pending for him to legally sign in the 11:59-12:01 period.

Comment: @bvoyelr It's unlikely that whatever the Supreme Court decides will blanketly apply to _all_ executive orders. The due process rights of DACA participants are a significant part of the issue at hand.

Comment: @JustinLardinois It's more the idea that the courts even have standing to review decisions to sundown executive actions that the office unilaterally implemented in the first place.  In any decision of consequence, there will always be some factor that justifies the review.